# Microsoft Toolkit DataGrid not refresh data in view

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, toolkit

I have datagrid to show some data in xaml of UWP application.I use MVVM and a i have view model for the view. Items source of datagrid is observable collection. I have problem with refresh data on xaml view. If i us DataGridTextColumn as column data, data refreshed properly on view, but if i use DataGridTemplateColumn data on view not refresh.

This code work properly:

```
<mtc:DataGrid Name="ArticlesListView"
  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Articles, Mode=OneWay}"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
  IsReadOnly="True">
  <mtc:DataGrid.Columns>
     <mtc:DataGridTextColumn Header="Barcode" Binding="{Binding Barcode}"/>
     <mtc:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
  </mtc:DataGrid.Columns>
 </mtc:DataGrid>
```

I clear and fill observable collection with new data and data on view is refresh properly.

This code not work properly:

```
<mtc:DataGrid Name="ArticlesListView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Articles, Mode=OneWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
    IsReadOnly="True">
    <mtc:DataGrid.Columns>
       <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Barcode">
          <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <controls:DataGridCell Background="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" 
                                                   Data="{Binding Barcode}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
         <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <controls:DataGridCell Background="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" 
                                                   Data="{Binding Description}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
         </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn>                
     </mtc:DataGrid.Columns>
  </mtc:DataGrid>
```

I clear and fill observable collection with new data but on view stays old data.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you for help. I figured out the problem. The problem is that property change event does not reach the custom control that i made for DataTemplate and changes does not apply in it. I change this lines of code:

```
<mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Barcode" Tag="Barcode">
  <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <controls:DataGridCell Background="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" 
                             Data="{Binding Barcode}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

to this:

```
<mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Barcode" Tag="Barcode">
  <mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>     
      <Grid Background="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Barcode, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToStringConverter}}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource DataGridCellContentStyle}"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</mtc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and everything works fine. Its just have to define DataTemplate in datagrid not use external user control for DataTemplate because changes does not reach user control and does not apply to the view.

Comment: Please tell me which version of DataGrid you're using. With my tests, there's no `Data` property in it.

Comment: Besides, Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis. Your above code was not enough to do troubleshooting.

Comment: Data property is a dependancy property of custom user control that i made. DataGridCell is custom control it is not a part of datagrid. Version of datagrid that iuse is 5.1.0

Comment: So, as I said, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for help. I figured out the problem. Look question i add the solution in it.